# Необычный слайдер отзывов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как можно сделать такой слайдер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все блоки идентичны, т.е. имеют фотографию, отзыв и другую информацию.
 Нужно сделать так, чтобы у активного отзыва показывалась вся эта информация, а у неактивных отзывов (отмечены кружками на скриншоте) показывалась лишь фотография.

При этом при нажатии по стрелкам должен открываться другой отзыв, а при нажатии на картинки должен открываться соответствующий картинке отзыв, и все это должно происходить с плавной анимацией, как у слайдера.

Возможно есть какие-либо библиотеки для этого, подскажите кто уже сталкивался с этим, как это реализовать?

Comment: что тут необычного я не пойму

Comment: То, что здесь есть активный слайд, и пассивные(миниатюры - только фотографии)

Comment: @Shillkas Так ведь и слайдеры не всегда одна картинка на весь экран... Весьма заурядная задача, воспользуйтесь каким-нибудь `owl` или `slick-slider`, вешайте обработчик события на каждый слайд, при клике - убирайте у других слайдов класс `active`, кликнутому - давайте. И уже с помощью `css` показывайте текст только у активных слайдов, примерно так: `.slide-container.active .text-container {display:block;}`

Comment: А Вы сами используете какую то библиотеку для реализации slider'а? К примеру, при использовании библиотеки owl-carousel активные элементы автоматически получают класс active

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу